# Find two numbers which are divisible without remainder

Tags: c#, algorithm, numbers

The numbers are generated randomly. In the specified range. For example, it is two numbers: 5 and 10, well 10 divides 5. If it's 5 and 2, it is not divide. The 2 required to reduce by 1 or 5 to increase by 1. Tell me a fast algorithm?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "The 2 required to reduce by 1 or 5 to increase by 1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1. Let A is greater and B is smaller
2. Set M = (A % B)
3. If M == 0, You're done..
4. Else Adjust A  either by adding, A = A + B - M
5.               or by subtracting, A = A - M
```

Answer (score 2):

`a%b==0` is true if `b` divides `a` without remainder

Comment: If `b` does not divide `a`, he needs them to be adjusted until there's no remainder.

Comment: True, but not the question that was asked.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!(temp1 % temp2))) 
    temp1= temp1 + (temp1%temp2)
else 
   tadaaaaa :)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (val1 > val2) { 
   rem = val1 % val2 ;
   if (rem == 0) you're done
   otherwise required_addition = val2 + rem
} else if (val1 < val2) { 
    required_addition = val2 - val1;
} else {
    they are the same; you are done;
}
```

Comment: What does `required_addition` do?

Comment: @Hippo, it's a new number that's divisible by val1.

Comment: @AtoMerZ: If `val1` is 4, and `val2` is 10, `required_addition` will be 10+4=14, which isn't divisible by 4.

Comment: val1 is evenly divisible by val2 + required_addition.  I think that's what the OP wanted.

Comment: @AtoMerZ, not correct. For example, 21 and 5, remainder is equal 1. Therefore, 5 + 1 = 6, but 21 not divide by 6.

Comment: @Hippo you are correct - for some reason I thought val1 was guaranteed to be > val2.  I corrected my answer. +1 for noticing!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using division, it would be easier to construct a pair of numbers that can be divided with no remainder. Pick the first number at random, `a` say, then pick another number at random, `b` say, and then set `c = a*b`.